# How to automate in JAVA the generation of HMAC signature for a request having request body

Tags: java, postman

My question is what happens to the Request body when generating the HMACSHA256 signature from POSTMAN. I am looking to automate this in Java, but I am not sure on what change I need to make to the request body. Just sending the request body like I would for any other POST request is not working.

The HMAC signature generated with the request headers and body as shown below works for GET requests but not for POST requests.

[image: POST request]

[image: Request Body]

EDIT: Adding in the code I have so far

The below function I am assigning the Key, Secret key and the referer.

```
        Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
        headerMap.put("SecretKey", gds.API_KEY);
        headerMap.put("KeyID", gds.API_KEY_ID);
        //headerMap.put("Referer", gds.API_HOST_NAME + endpoint);
        headerMap.put("Referer", "https://td-api.qa1.sac.int.threatmetrix.com/api/v1/add_element_identifier/687gh7ih");
        APIQuery api = new APIQuery(logger);
        String authorization = api.QueryHttpPostWithHeaderAuth("END_POINT_AUTH", headerMap, JsonBody);
        api.printOutputParameters();
        return authorization.substring(1, authorization.length() - 1);
    }


        public String QueryHttpPostWithHeaderAuth( String endPoint, Map<String, String> headerMap, String reqBodyHash){
            HttpPost request;
            try {
                CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
                request = new HttpPost(GlobalDataStore.API_SERVER + "v1/support/generate/authheader");
                if(!headerMap.isEmpty())
                    headerMap.forEach((k,v) -> request.setHeader(k, v));

                StringEntity body = new StringEntity(reqBodyHash);

                //could override default content type
                String contentType = this.contentType == null ? "application/json":this.contentType;
                request.addHeader("content-type", contentType);
                request.setEntity(body);

                //post the json req
                CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);


                //read the response
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
                this.statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    jsonResponse=line;
                }

                rd.close();
                httpClient.close();
                data = "";
            } catch(Exception e){
                Assert.assertTrue(false, String.valueOf(e));
            }
            return jsonResponse;
        }


    //https://developer.cybersource.com/docs/cybs/en-us/platform/developer/all/rest/rest-getting-started/restgs-http-message-conf-intro/restgs-http-message-conf-payload-hash.html
    public static String GenerateDigest(String API_KEY, String reqBody) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String bodyText = reqBody;
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(bodyText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        return "SHA-256=" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digest);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement the same method that Postman does? Where are you stuck? Share your code.

Comment: @aled I have edited my post and added the code what I have so far. Here I have attempted to generate SHA-256 hash of the JSON payload. 
But I am not sure how to pass it? IN QueryHttpPostWithHeaderAuth, I have used request.setEntity(body); just like I owuld set a message body for a normal POST request. But this does not seem to work. 
However in POSTMAN I am able to set the api, header, body etc and generate the HMAC signature.